# The question about QMediaPlayer playback MP4 program exits abnormally

Tags: c++, qt, mp4

When using QMedaiPlayer in QT to play MP4 files, the build passes normally, and the program quits abnormally during runtime, which has troubled me for many days. I hope everyone can help!

1. There is no problem with the build, and it exits abnormally during runtime.
2. The replacement of a smaller MP4 file still does not work, so it is not a matter of MP4 file size.
3. The use of MKV files will not work, nor is it a file format issue.
4. The version is QT 5.12.8

This is the mainwindow.cpp file

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow){

    this->setFixedSize(1024,576);
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QHBoxLayout  *m_layout= new QHBoxLayout(this);
    QMediaPlayer *m_player = new QMediaPlayer(this);

    m_player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QString::fromLocal8Bit("D:/try.mkv")));

    m_videoW = new QVideoWidget(this);
    m_layout->addWidget(m_videoW);
    this->setLayout(m_layout);

    m_player->setVideoOutput(m_videoW);
    m_videoW->show();
    m_player->play();

    qDebug()<<"hello";
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *){

    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.drawPixmap(0,0,width(),height(), m_videoW->currentPixmap());

}
```

This is the mainwindow.h file

```
    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*);
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QVideoWidget *m_videoW；

};
```

The corresponding library is also added to the pro file:

```
QT       += core gui
QT       += multimedia
QT       += multimediawidgets
```

I never found where the problem is, please help me find it! Thank you!

Test with qDebug, hello can output normally.

*The code has been displayed according to the principle of least recurrence.

Comment: `m_videoW->show();` seems not needed, you need to show() only the `MainWindow`.
Would be nice to see the full code, I'm not sure what goes where since the `{` and `}` are omitted...

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answers! The complete code is posted here. The omission of the latter is mainly because this problem has little to do with the following code. In addition, I tried it, even if it was changed to show(), it did not solve this headache problem.  @tr3w